# Subtle difference between statemetns invloving negation in set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

What is the difference between the statements `$x$ is not in an infinite number of sets $E_n$` and `It is not the case that $x$ is in an infinite number of sets $E_n$`? Does the later imply the former?

How should I formalize these statements in mathematical logic?

Comment: "It is not the case that $A$" is the same as "not $A$", i.e. $\lnot A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How can I formalize the statement that $x$ is in an infinite number of $n$ in simple logic notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the first sentence, as written, is ambiguous. It could either be interpreted as

> A) There is not an infinite number of $E_n$'s all of which contain $x$.
>
> B) There is an infinite number of $E_n$'s such that $x$ is
>   contained in none of them.

The sentence A) is equivalent to your second sentence "it is not the case that $x$ is in an infinite number of sets $E_n$."

Assuming the $E_n$ are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, to say that $x$ is in infinitely many $E_n$ is to say that for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $n\geq N$ such that $x \in E_n$. So
$$x \text{ is in infinitely many } E_n \Leftrightarrow \forall N\  \exists n \ (n \geq N \wedge x \in E_n)$$
Thus
\begin{align*}\text{it is not the case that $x$ is infinitely many $E_n$} &\Leftrightarrow \neg \forall N \ \exists n \ (n \geq N \wedge x \in E_n)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists N \ \forall n \ (n<N \vee x \notin E_n)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists N \ \forall n \ (n \geq N \Rightarrow x \notin E_n).
\end{align*}

That is, past some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, none of the $E_n$ for $n \geq N$ contains $x$. So sentence A) is also equivalent to "$x$ is in only finitely many $E_n$."

Now sentence B) just says that $x$ is in infinitely many of the $E_n^C$'s. I.e.,
$$\text{there is an infinite number of $E_n$ not containing $x$} \Leftrightarrow \forall N \ \exists n \ (n \geq N \wedge x \notin E_n).$$

Note that this doesn't tell us anything about whether $x$ is in finitely many or infinitely many $E_n$'s.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is ambiguous. It could mean either "There is an infinite number of sets $E_n$ for which $x\notin E_n$", or it could mean "There is only a finite number of sets $E_n$ for which $x\in E_n$".

The second statement can only mean the latter.

**Addendum:** For the first statement, suppose $\mathscr E$ is the collection of all $E_n$ under consideration, and put $$\mathscr E'=\{E\in \mathscr E : x\in E\}$$ The two alternatives are $$\mathscr E' \textrm{ is finite}\tag{1}$$ and $$\mathscr E\setminus \mathscr E' \textrm{ is infinite}\tag{2}$$
On the other hand, the second statement is the latter of the two alternatives above.